# QGIS - selection with data from excel

Tags: qgis, query

I have a line layer with roads. Every road has a unique start and endpointnumber, as attribute. From this layer I want to select some roads. Therefore I have an excel table with start- and endpoint, which I want to select. The road layer and the excel table don´t have an id, for a join.
Is there any option in the query builder, that I can use columns from the table for my query on the line layer?

part of the excel table

[image]

part of the attribute table of road layer
[image]

I want to select all roads with the values of "vnk" and "nnk" from the excel table, but I can´t join them.

Comment: Could you paste a couple of screenshots of the attribute table for your road layer and your Excel layer so we can see how your data is structured more clearly? I think what you want to do is possible but you have to use Select Features by Expression and expressions that essentially perform joins (either `get_feature()` or `aggregate()`)

Comment: You could create an ID by combining the "vnk" and "nnk" fields?

Comment: No, the attributes "vnk" and "nnk" are not unique in the line layer. The excel table is a list of "vnk" and "nnk" values,which I want to select from the line layer. But I don´t want to select all separatly.

Comment: Yeah, but the combination "vnk-nnk" should be unique?

Comment: So you want to select roads where either vnk or nnk field values are in excel file nnk field?

Comment: I want to use the tool select by expression and need a statement, which allows me to select objects from the layer road. The objects which I need are stored in the excel table. And I want to say "take all objects from layer road with the value "vnk" = value "vnk" from excel table" . I dont want to join them or create another ID - sorry for the difficult explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to select all road features that have the **exact same `vnk` and `nnk` combination** as a row in your Excel table - then you can use this expression in Select by Expression:

`get_feature('excel','vnk',"vnk") is not null AND get_feature('excel','nnk',"nnk") is not null`

[image]

If you want to select all road features where the `vnk` value must be in the Excel table, and the `nnk` value must also be in the Excel table, **but not necessarily in the exact same pair combination**, then you can use this expression.

`get_feature('excel','vnk',"vnk") is not null OR get_feature('excel','nnk',"nnk") is not null`

[image]

---

For both expressions you need to change the name of your `excel` layer accordingly (please note it is case-sensitive)